# App won't adjust layout on tablet mode with resizable AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-reply-app/tree/starter

Running the code in a resizable AVD set on tablet display mode won't adjust the layout of the app (navigation on the left instead at the bottom).

What could be the reasons an app won't adjust?

Screenshots available here of how it's supposed to be (according to the codelab): https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-adaptive-navigation-for-large-screens#4

Comment: opened https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-reply-app/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is expected that the navigation remains at the bottom despite the resizable AVD is configured as tablet ( see step @ https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-adaptive-navigation-for-large-screens?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-adaptive-navigation-for-large-screens#6 )

The previous step is worded wrongly creating expectation that the navigation should be on the left in various modes (portrait/landscape) of the virtual tablet.